# Are data-urls in code snippets frowned upon or encouraged?

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-snippets, images

When posting an answer with a runnable code snippet that needs to include an image, should the `src` attribute refer to an external url, or should the image be encoded as a data-uri?

(+) the data-uri does not break
(-) it feels wrong to have so much data inside an answer

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Comment: "it feels wrong to have so much data inside an answer" It also triggers an automatic flag that usually serves as little more than a waste of our time :V

Comment: I'll take that as "frowned upon"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about uploading it to SE's imgur account (by doing the standard "include image from my computer"-dance), and then referencing that?

Or if the exact image does not matter, consider re-purposing one already there.

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZoQ.png">
```

In general, I find such big blobs distracting.

Comment: Why not simply use the images at http://lorempixel.com/?

Comment: @Xufox: Because SE has a deal with imgur which means those images will stay online as long as SE.